# Are OBJECT & EMBED tags always on top?

Tags: html, flash

> I have a site I made that I am streaming video on, its starting to
>   look pretty cool but  the menu I made in CSS is always under the video
>   so some of the links dissappear behind the object.
>
> Does anyone know if I can fix this, I think I tried z-index one time
>   to no avail?

I just reposted this question since this is also my problem.

Comment: Added the `flash` tag because OP stated in comments that his video is a Flash object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `wmode="transparent"` (transparent background) or `wmode="opaque"` (opaque background affected by `bgcolor`).

The default value is `window` which means that the object will have its own "window", so it is not affected by anything else in the webpage at all. If you set it to `transparent` or `opaque`, it will become "a part of the page".

Like:

```
<object ...>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" /> 
    ...
    <embed  wmode="transparent" ...></embed>
</object>
```

This only applies to **Flash** AFAIK.

Comment: Doesn't this apply only to Flash movies?

Comment: @Pekka Thanks, added. I assumed this is a Flash movie.

Comment: @bažmegakapa: is there any work aroud for other objects such as 3dxml player object?

Comment: @john Never tried that. Check the docs and if you cannot find any information, writing them an email could be a good idea.

Comment: for anyone wondering how this works in 2015, the `<embed  wmode="transparent" ...>` section is all you need (at least in firefox) and no need to worry about setting wmode in `url`'s `param`'s or `iframe`s

Answer (score 2):

What object is rendered with your `object`/`embed` tags? Is it Flash? If so, you can set the parameter `wmode` to `transparent` or `opaque` to regain x-order control.

See this [tech note from Adobe](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15523.html) for more info.

If you're not rendering Flash, you'll need to look into the available parameters from the supplier of the plugin (i.e. Apple for Quicktime etc) to see whether anything similar is on offer.

Comment: When you right click, do you get a Flash menu? I think utube still use Flash, but I'm not 100%.

Comment: Yes. It does have a flash menu.

Answer (score 1):

They are not "always on top" by definition, but some plugins don't quite support Z ordering, and some need to be given extra parameters to enable elements on top of the video. Flash, for instance, requires a [wmode parameter](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15523.html) to obey Z ordering.

What plugin are you using?